# How to bind an HTTP-date request header to ZonedDateTime in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datetime, java-8

In my Spring MVC controller I would like to bind headers in the [HTTP-date format](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1) (e.g. for If-Modified-Since) to instances of ZonedDateTime like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public ResponseEntity<?> someRequest(
    @RequestHeader(value = "If-Modified-Since") ZonedDateTime modifiedSince)
{
    ...
}
```

I've looked at annotating the parameter with `@DateTimeFormat`, but this does not provide a built-in way to parse all the formats accepted for HTTP dates. Is there some way to get Spring to bind the header parameter correctly?

Comment: Java-8 only yields a [partial solution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) - for the rfc1123-part. To model the alternative rfc850-part which uses full week-day-names (and the "asc-time-date"), you have probably to catch exceptions in case the first try with rfc1123 fails.

Answer (score 0):

You must to use the ISO option inside the interface @DateTimeFormat, as shown in the Spring [documentations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
```